# Generating interaction terms manually

Tags: r, panel-data

I am trying to estimate a fixed effects panel with individual-specific time trends using `plm` and am running up against the same problem as [other people](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24131/using-r-and-plm-to-estimate-fixed-effects-models-that-include-interactions-with). I'm more than willing to use the workaround described in the linked CrossValidated question but cannot figure out how to generate the necessary data frame columns.

That is, I have a data frame of the form

```
data.frame(date=rep(1:5,times=3),id=rep(1:3,each=5))
```

and would like to add to this data frame a column for each `id` that is named `date_idX`, has the same value as `date` for all observations where `id==X` and zero otherwise.

Any more elegant solutions to my problem would of course also be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean same value as 'date'?

Answer (score 1):

```
> dfrm <- data.frame(date=rep(1:5,times=3),id=rep(1:3,each=5))
> 
> X <-3;  dfrm$time_idX <- dfrm$date*(dfrm$id==X)
> dfrm
   date id time_idX
1     1  1        0
2     2  1        0
3     3  1        0
4     4  1        0
5     5  1        0
6     1  2        0
7     2  2        0
8     3  2        0
9     4  2        0
10    5  2        0
11    1  3        1
12    2  3        2
13    3  3        3
14    4  3        4
15    5  3        5
```

I suspect that what your really wanted was to do this in a regression formula. For that the `I()` function is needed. This is pseudo-code:

```
  regfun( form = yield ~ I(date*(id==X) ), data=dfrm)
```

I'm not guaranteeing this will be a proper solution to the problem of using plm, but is a method that should work with ordinary regression. You should edit your question to include a proper test case.

Comment: It seems I did not make myself clear enough in the question: I tried simply putting `date*id` into the formula, but this does not work in `plm`, for reasons mentioned in the linked CrossValidated question. The suggested fix is to create these individual-specific time trends by hand and then to add them to the formula. And since I have something like 300 individuals, I would need 300 variables which contain a time trend each. The `date_idX` was thus supposed to stand for the whole lot of `date_id1`, `date_id2`, `date_id3` and so on.

Comment: Actually I see no mention of a term that I understood to be date*id. I saw a model similar to  y ~ date + date:id. My suggestion is to create a reduced dataframe with, say 4 individuals and 5 time periods, and work with a more manageable "testbed". Then you can work up to 300. There are R-SIG mailing lists for both econ and mixed-effects topics.